# Android TaskView produces ClassCastException

Tags: android, runtime-error, classcastexception

My grandfather is proud owner of a Samsung Galaxy Ace 2. He now told me that whenever he presses the home-button long to open the task view he gets an error "Unfortunately, System UI has stopped"

I know investigated on this and tried to reproduce the error while being connected to the android monitor to get a more specific error message.

The error message looks like the following:

```
01-22 12:44:42.450 4978-4978/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
                                                     at com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsPanelView.replaceGoogleButtonTo3rdAppTextAndIcon(RecentsPanelView.java:1444)
                                                     at com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsPanelView.replaceGoogleButtonTextAndIcon(RecentsPanelView.java:1392)
                                                     at com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsPanelView.show(RecentsPanelView.java:461)
                                                     at com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsPanelView.showIfReady(RecentsPanelView.java:391)
                                                     at com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsPanelView.onTasksLoaded(RecentsPanelView.java:1015)
                                                     at com.android.systemui.recent.RecentTasksLoader$1.onProgressUpdate(RecentTasksLoader.java:292)
                                                     at com.android.systemui.recent.RecentTasksLoader$1.onProgressUpdate(RecentTasksLoader.java:285)
                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:647)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 12:44:42.460 1988-2005/? E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

There is no custom rom installed or any other custom application. The latest updates already are installed. After searching the web, I did a wipe of the cache in the recovery menu also I made a full reset of the mobile phone. Nothin helped by now.

Maybe some of you may have an idea on what to investigate any further?

Comment: It's look like a bug in Google App 6.10.37.16.arm 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=232694